# custom jar contents for executable jar built with IntelliJ & maven

Tags: maven, jar, intellij-idea, maven-2

The person for whom I'm building an executable JAR file wants all externally needed libraries in a separate `lib/` directory that will be in his current working directory when he runs my JAR.  He also asked that I pull the `log4j.xml` and `config.properties` files out of the JAR so he can edit their values.  How would I build a JAR with such a manifest using IntelliJ and maven?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with the help of a few `Maven` plugins.

To get all `dependencies` into a different folder use the `maven-dependency-plugin`. This example puts them in the `target/lib` folder.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>copy-dependencies</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib/</outputDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

And to put the specified `resources` into a different folder use the `maven-resources-plugin`

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>copy-resources</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>                    
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/conf</outputDirectory>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
            <includes>
              <include>log4j.xml</include>
              <include>config.properties</include>
            </includes>
          </resource>
        </resources>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then finally, you need to use the `maven-jar-plugin` to perform the following:

1. Exclude the resources from the jar
2. Reference all the dependencies in the lib folder in your jar's manifest
3. Reference the resources in the conf folder in your jar's manifest

Something like the following should work:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>foo.bar.Main</mainClass>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Class-Path>conf/</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
                <classifier>jar-without-resources</classifier>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>log4j.properties</exclude>
                    <exclude>config.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>                
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Hope this helps,

Will